# How do you implement IDataRecord properly if IndexOutOfRangeException is a reserved exception type?

Tags: .net, exception, interface, fxcop

According to the documentation for [IDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getfieldtype.aspx), the implementing methods must throw IndexOutOfRangeException if the field index is out of the range of fields. However, if you try to throw an IndexOutOfRangeException directly in code, FXCop complains that it is a reserved exception type. How do you keep to the IDataRecord exception contract while still keeping FXCop happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore FXCop in the case.

It's perfectly reasonable to throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` when it's the most appropriate exception to throw - e.g. if you're implementing `IList<T>`.

You might want to remove it from your FXCop configuration...